# Make chart fill size of browser window

Tags: c#, plotly.net

## Screenshot

I have a C# program which uses Plotly.NET to set up a candlestick chart of the S&P data.

It's shown below in a browser window:

[image]

## Question

Is there a way to get it to be larger? Perhaps a way to get it to fill the window?

## Responsive charts

The documentation has a [section](https://plotly.net/00_3_chart-config.html#Responsive-charts) regarding *Responsive charts*:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using to setup the chart:

```cs
Chart2D.Chart.Candlestick<string>(seq)

    .WithYAxis(LinearAxis.init<IConvertible, IConvertible, IConvertible, IConvertible, IConvertible, IConvertible>(
        FixedRange: false))

    .WithConfig(Config.init(Responsive: true))

    .Show();
```

However, the resulting chart is still a fixed size.

## Code

Here's a [link](https://github.com/dharmatech/PlotlyNetCandlestickCsv/blob/master/TetherDepegPlotlyNet/Program.cs) to the full program, if you'd like to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the chart can be changed via `WithSize` as shown below:

```cs
Chart2D.Chart.Candlestick<string>(seq)

    .WithYAxis(LinearAxis.init<IConvertible, IConvertible, IConvertible, IConvertible, IConvertible, IConvertible>(
        FixedRange: false))

    .WithConfig(Config.init(Responsive: true))

    .WithSize(1800, 900)

    .Show();
```